# Query to show difference over time in the data

Tags: database, postgresql, relational-database

Lets say I have a table that shows attendence to a lecture. The table is very simple, it only contains the date of the lecture, and the attendees.

```
2016-10-10 | Adam
2016-10-10 | Mike
2016-10-10 | David
2016-10-11 | Adam
2016-10-14 | Adam
2016-10-14 | David
```

What I would like is a query to show what percentage of the attendees for each lecture that was present on the previous lecture. Can this be done in a effective way?

The expected result would be something like this:

```
2016-10-11 | 1.00
2016-10-14 | 0.50
```

2016-10-10 would be left out since it does not have a previous lecture.

Comment: What are your expected results?  On 2016-10-10 it would be 100% on 2016-10-11 it would be 33% and on 10-14 it would be 66%?  If so then you're after the average over day? How do we know the total class size (do we assume the day with the most students was the total enrolled (What happens if Jane simply hasn't show up yet)?  How do you distinguish between classes?

Comment: How do you identify the "previous class"? Is a class always just a single day?

Comment: I have edited the question, I think my english made the question unclear.

Comment: Read about "window functions". Also keep googling SO for what you are trying to do.